# How to create a reusable object that embeds different other objects?

Tags: go

I have many different models:

```
type objectModel struct {
        Title string `json:"title"`
        Body string `json:"body"`
}

// Many more models...
```

These models are used to create response objects that are returned to clients. All responses must contain a boolean OK value; other fields depend on the context.

```
type objectResponse struct {
        OK bool `json:"ok"`
        Object *objectModel `json:"object"`
}

type objectListResponse struct {
        OK bool `json:"ok"`
        Objects []*objectModel `json:"objects"`
}

// Many more response types that are similar to these two examples.
```

#### Problem

What I want to have is a reusable `response` object that embeds all these different custom response objects `objectResponse`, `objectListResponse` and so on. In this case I wouldn't need to define `OK bool` on every response object I have. I would use it like this: `response.write(responseWriter)`, but that's out of the scope of this question.

```
type response struct {
    OK bool `json:"ok"`
    CustomResponse
}
```

It should be possible with an interface, but I don't know what common method all of the responses should implement.

Comment: why do you need Ok property ? aren't http status codes enough ?

Comment: Is there more to this or is the entire goal to eliminate a single line of code per struct?

Answer (score 1):

> What I want to have is a reusable response object that embeds all these different custom response objects objectResponse, objectListResponse and so on. In this case I wouldn't need to define OK bool on every response object I have.

What about doing the opposite: have a reusable Response object that is embedded in your custom response objects?  That would allow you to not define OK bool on every response object (your stated goal), you would just embed the Response struct in each one.  If there are other repeated fields you could use the same embedded struct for those as well, or another struct if they only belong in some custom responses.

Here's a simplified working example:

```
package main

import(
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
)

type Response struct {
    OK          bool        `json:"ok"`
}

type lookResponse struct {
    Response
    Color       string      `json:"color"`
    Shape       string      `json:"shape"`
}

func main() {
    b := []byte(`{"ok":true,"color":"blue","shape":"circle"}`)
    var r lookResponse
    err := json.Unmarshal(b, &r)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error: %s\n", err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("ok: %v, color: %v, shape: %v\n", r.OK, r.Color, r.Shape)
}
```

When run that prints:

```
ok: true, color: blue, shape: circle
```

You can read more about embedded fields in the [Go Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types), e.g.:

> A field declared with a type but no explicit field name is called an
>   embedded field... A field or method f of an embedded field in a struct
>   x is called promoted if x.f is a legal selector that denotes that
>   field or method f. Promoted fields act like ordinary fields of a
>   struct except that they cannot be used as field names in composite
>   literals of the struct.

If that doesn't solve your issue, please clarify your goals/question.

Answer (score 0):

I would use an `interface{}` there. For example:

```
type response struct {
    OK bool `json:"ok"`
    Object interface{} `json:"object"`
}
```

Now when I want to use I can put any other types there:

```
res := response{
    OK: true,
    Object: varOfCustomObjectModel,
}
```

Here is a response object that I used for one of my project:
https://github.com/leninhasda/gitpull-me/blob/master/api/response.go

Use case:

```
res := &response{
    StatusCode: http.StatusOK,
    Data: map[string]interface{}{
        "product_title": "Awesome Product",
        "price": 188.99,
        "quantity": 1,
        "meta": map[string]interface{}{
            "height": 10,
            "width": 15,
        },
    },
    // or as simple as just 
    // Data: "hello world!"
}
res.json(w) // w is http.ResponseWriter
```

Comment: I had this solution in mind, but it's not what I'm looking for right now.

Comment: I would avoid this solution because it completely abandons type safety and means you'll likely have to do a lot of type assertions or reflection.